# Table-Listbox databinding not resulting in data displayed

Tags: c#, .net, xaml

I suspect the error "Cannot create an instance of MainViewModel" is to blame, but to be completely honest, I'm not sure. It's the only error Visual Studio is giving me, and code compiles and runs despite it; the problem I'm having is that my Listbox isn't displaying data from my table.

Relevant sample from MainPage.xaml:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    x:Class="CarpetQuote.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignData SampleData/MainViewModelSampleData.xaml}" />

    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <ListBox x:Name="MainListBox" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Carpets}" SelectionChanged="MainListBox_SelectionChanged" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding carpetName}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

MainViewModelSampleData.xaml below; this is the page responsible for "Cannot create an instance of MainViewModel".

```
<local:MainViewModel 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"  
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CarpetQuote"
    SampleProperty="Sample Value">

    <local:MainViewModel.Items>
        <local:ItemViewModel LineOne="design one" LineTwo="Maecenas praesent accumsan bibendum" LineThree="Maecenas praesent accumsan bibendum dictumst eleifend facilisi faucibus habitant inceptos interdum lobortis nascetur"/>
        <local:ItemViewModel LineOne="design two" LineTwo="Dictumst eleifend facilisi faucibus" LineThree="Pharetra placerat pulvinar sagittis senectus sociosqu suscipit torquent ultrices vehicula volutpat maecenas praesent"/>
        <local:ItemViewModel LineOne="design three" LineTwo="Habitant inceptos interdum lobortis" LineThree="Accumsan bibendum dictumst eleifend facilisi faucibus habitant inceptos interdum lobortis nascetur pharetra placerat"/>
        <local:ItemViewModel LineOne="design four" LineTwo="Nascetur pharetra placerat pulvinar" LineThree="Pulvinar sagittis senectus sociosqu suscipit torquent ultrices vehicula volutpat maecenas praesent accumsan bibendum"/>
        <local:ItemViewModel LineOne="design five" LineTwo="Sagittis senectus sociosqu suscipit" LineThree="Dictumst eleifend facilisi faucibus habitant inceptos interdum lobortis nascetur pharetra placerat pulvinar sagittis"/>
        <local:ItemViewModel LineOne="design six" LineTwo="Torquent ultrices vehicula volutpat" LineThree="Senectus sociosqu suscipit torquent ultrices vehicula volutpat maecenas praesent accumsan bibendum dictumst eleifend"/>
    </local:MainViewModel.Items>
</local:MainViewModel>
```

I've read a little about the error elsewhere, but nothing quite seems to help. General consensus seems to be that the compiler doesn't like something in my MainViewModel constructor, but I the only line there, `db = new CarpetContext(App.ConnString);`, is necessary, and I have functionally identical code running without the error in another project.

If this error is not to blame for the failed binding, here are relevant portions of App.xaml.cs, where the database is created.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private static MainViewModel viewModel = null;

    public static MainViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            if (viewModel == null)
            {
                viewModel = new MainViewModel();
            }

            return viewModel;
        }
    }

    private static string connString = null;
    public static string ConnString { get { return connString; } }
    public App()
    {
        // Autogenerated code and comments snipped

        if (connString == null)
        {
            connString = Resources["IsoDBConn"] as string;
        }
        createDB();
    }

    private void createDB()
    {
        using (var db = new CarpetContext(ConnString))
        {
            if (!db.DatabaseExists())
            {
                db.CreateDatabase();
            }
        }
    }

    private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!App.ViewModel.isDataLoaded)
        {
            App.ViewModel.loadData();
        }
    }
}
```

And finally (I feel really bad about the wall of code), the referenced functions from MainViewModel.

```
public bool IsDataLoaded
{
    get;
    private set;
}

public void loadData()
{
    db.Carpets.InsertOnSubmit(new Carpet("StainMaster", 10));
    db.Carpets.InsertOnSubmit(new Carpet("Windsor", 12));
    db.Carpets.InsertOnSubmit(new Carpet("Homfray", 11.5m));
    db.Carpets.InsertOnSubmit(new Carpet("Wall Street", 15));
    db.Carpets.InsertOnSubmit(new Carpet("Axminster", 16.5m));
    db.SubmitChanges();
    Carpets = new ObservableCollection<Carpet>(db.Carpets.ToList());
    this.isDataLoaded = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is a weird one, but I was working on this on another computer and... it worked.

Turns out the problem is with my Windows Phone SDK install. The listbox is indeed populating, but the text isn't visible.

This is probably too localised to be useful, would suggest closing.